# Use ons.enableAutoStatusBarFill in in onsen ui with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

i am completely new to Angularjs trying to understand how can i use `ons.enableAutoStatusBarFill();` this so i my menus wont over take the status bar.

here is how i have my controller setup.

```
var mod = ons.bootstrap('app', ['onsen']);

mod.controller('MyControler', function($scope) {

ons.ready(function() {

            // code inside...

    });           
});
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. I am using this reference http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UtilityAPIs

**I tried to solve it this way**

```
var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);
var module = ons.enableAutoStatusBarFill();
```

It seems like working but its not finding my controllers now. Getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is

Comment: I think `enableAutoStatusBarFill` is the default behaviour. In either case, it should be called in the beginning, not inside `ons.ready` nor AngularJS controller. Docs are here: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#disableautostatusbarfill

Comment: I tried placing it everywhere but its not working... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. Actually the cordoda file was at the bottom of my page. Due to which the page was not able to load properly.

Now i added in this pattern in my index.html and got it resolved.

```
 <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script> //This should be added first before the main custom.js file which starts my module.

  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Thank you for all your support!